# Pull that data from sheet and create a PDF with that data

Tags: date, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need someone to help me write a script for this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14JgHIvp8aEyDaHYcExWWQM9E0lTdg0W5Jb-UzWIHHX0/edit#gid=0 Sheet1 and the data will vary in row count both up and down each month.

I need a script is date triggered I can setup the date trigger but what I want is on the first of each month I need the script to pull that data on Sheet1 (varying in row count) and create a PDF with that data. Then save that PDF to my Drive with the name made of the Month and some text so, for example, this month would look like "May Form Data" and then email that PDF to me. So then on the 1st of the next month, it would create the new PDF and title it "June Form Data" and email it to me. This would happen every month as the data on the sheet will change every month. The data on the sheet will be pulled in with formula from other sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Monthly Report**

You supply: the trigger, SpreadsheetId, SheetName, your email address and the FolderId.

```
function firstDayOfTheMonthReport() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetId');
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    if(shts[i].getName()!='SheetName') {
      shts[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }
  var fileid=ss.getId();
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderId');
  var name=Utilities.formatString('%s Form Data', Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM"));
  var fileblob=DriveApp.getFileById(fileid).getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(name);
  var file=folder.createFile(fileblob);
  GmailApp.sendEmail('your email', 'Monthly Report', 'Report in Attachments', {attachments:[file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
}
```

**The version you requested and perhaps a little more.**

**PLEASE READ THESE INSTRUCTIONS BEFORE RUNNING THE SCRIPT**

1. You need to provide the Trigger.
2. You need to provide the SpreadsheetId.
3. You need to provide the FolderId where the pdf's are stored.
4. You need to provide your email address
5. You need to provide the names of the sheets that you want in the pdf.  You will need to put there names in pdfshtsA.  Like so: pdfshtsA=['SheetName1','SheetName2',.....].  You also put hidden sheets in the pdf report and they will be returned to hidden status after the report is sent.

**The Script:**

```
function firstDayOfTheMonthReport1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetId');//You have to provide this Spreadsheet Id
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var pdfshtsA=['Sheet1'];//You have to put sheetnames that you want included in pdf in here you can included hidden sheets if you wish they will hidden again after the pdfs are created and the email is sent.
  var visshtsA=[];//The script will put current visible sheets that are not in the above list
  var hidshtsA=[];//The script will put sheets that are in pdfshtsA but are currently hidden so that they can be in the pdf and then hidden afterward
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    if(pdfshtsA.indexOf(shts[i].getName()) == -1) {
      if(!shts[i].isSheetHidden()) {
        visshtsA.push(shts[i].getName());
        shts[i].hideSheet();
      }
    }else{
      if(shts[i].isSheetHidden()) {
        hidshtsA.push(shts[i].getName());
        shts[i].showSheet();
      }
    }
  }
  var fileid=ss.getId();
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderId');//You need to provide the FolderId
  var name=Utilities.formatString('%s Form Data', Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM"));
  var fileblob=DriveApp.getFileById(fileid).getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(name);
  var file=folder.createFile(fileblob);
  GmailApp.sendEmail('your email', 'Monthly Report', 'Report in Attachments', {attachments:[file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
  for(var i=0;i<visshtsA.length;i++) {
    ss.getSheetByName(visshtsA[i]).showSheet();
  }
  for(var i=0;i<hidshtsA.length;i++) {
    ss.getSheetByName(hidshtsA[i]).hideSheet();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, I put the code in and tried to run it, gave it permission then I get this error No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 10, file "Code") It appears it is not finding my Drive? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Ok, instead of my email I went into a folder within my Drive an pulled the ID from the end of the URL and it works now. Thank you again Cooper great work as before!

Comment: Well, one problem. I now see where it is hiding the other sheets so it only creates the one sheet as a PDF. Is there a way to not hide the sheets but still only pull the data from Sheet1 or maybe just a way to unhide the other sheets after the PDF is created? I have a couple other sheets that I need to remain visible in he end. Sorry for not fully clarifying that to begin with.

Comment: I would prefer if there is a way to modify this script to only pull the data from sheet1 and leave all the other alone. In my real sheet I have some that are hidden and I'd like them to stay hidden and some that are visible and I'd like them to stay that way also. I tried removing the if and changing the get sheets to getSheetByName but it still put all the sheets into the PDF. Here is how it looked when I changed it

Comment: var shts=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) ;

Comment: I think I can make a list of all the ones that are hidden and then assume that all the other ones should remain visible after this process is complete yeah I can modify it to do that.

Comment: I think it will work. Its giving me an error about the folder id saying it cant be found or i dont have permission. Both of those are false but I will try to play with the folder id some more and see if I can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: The folder id should have quotes around it.  It's a string.

Comment: I had quotes around it. It gives me a different folder ID when using a desktop vs my laptop. It works now when getting the folder ID on my desktop. I will have to look into what might have caused that but the important thing is your script works as it should. Very simple and easy to understand. Great code again Cooper and thank you for your help!

Comment: Oops, almost I guess. Just tried it on my live sheet and I need the orientation to be in landscape not portrait. I can't figure out how to change that. I dont see any parameters to change that output?

Comment: is there an easy way to set the PDF orientation to landscape? Should I start a new thread with your code and ask how to do that there? I don't want to ask too much of you but your code is always simple and easy to understand.

Comment: I think think the answer is that it's moved to the printer driver.